# Does $PA$ prove that $TREES$ maximises the Goodstein function?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $G(x)(k)$ denote the $k$-th term in the Goodstein sequence starting at $x$, and $\gamma(x)$ denote the [least] $k$ such that $G(x)(k) = 0$. We know that neither $\gamma$ nor $TREES$ are provably total in $PA$.

Consider the sentence $\sigma = \exists x_{0} \forall x > x_{0} (TREES(x) > \gamma (x))$. Does $PA$ prove $\sigma$?

Further comments: consider a machine $M$ that computes $TREES$ and a machine $N$ that computes $\gamma$. Then $\sigma$ can be seen as asserting "for all sufficiently large $x$, on input $x$, $N$ halts before $M$".
I can see for instance a model that thinks $\gamma$ is nontotal while $TREES$ is total thinking this sentence is false - at some nonstandard $x$, $\gamma$ will be undefined and thus $M$ will halt before $N$. The existence of such a model would imply the independence of $\sigma$ from $PA$. But can such a model exist?

Comment: When you write "$TREES(x)>\gamma(x)$," what exactly do you mean? Is this true if $TREES(x)$ and $\gamma(x)$ are both undefined? If one is undefined but the other isn't? (My understanding from your further comments is that undefined $>$ defined; is undefined $>$ undefined? Note that if the answer is no, then $PA$ certainly doesn't prove the statement in question.) By the way, although I don't think he answers your specific question, you should check out the [provability degrees](http://www2.ims.nus.edu.sg/Programs/014algo/files/cai1.pdf) introduced by Mingzhong Cai.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not understanding the first part of your comment - both $TREES$ and $\gamma$ are defined for all $x$.

Comment: Yes, *but the theory doesn't know that*. So when you ask a model of $PA$ "Does $TREES$ eventually dominate $\gamma$?", you need to clarify what you mean. If a model of $PA$ thinks $TREES$ is partial and $\gamma$ is total, does that model think that $TREES$ eventually dominates $\gamma$?

Comment: Oh yes. In that case, for an $x$ where allegedly $TREES$ is undefined and $\gamma$ is defined, $TREES(x) > \gamma(x)$ - I added the Turing machine analogy to clear this one up: if $TREES(x)$ is undefined and $\gamma(x)$ is defined, then $N$ will halt before $M$. Though I admit I missed the case where we have a model that thinks both functions are nontotal. I'm not sure of what happens then. Following the Turing machine analogy, I guess that for the $x$ where both are undefined, $PA$ does not decide "$TREES(x) > \gamma(x)$". What happens to $\sigma$ then?

Comment: Well, since it's consistent with PA that both $TREES$ and $\gamma$ are defined only finitely often, that would mean that $\sigma$ is not provable in $PA$. I think the right interpretation would be to have undefined > undefined (note that this matches a phenomenon common in logic: when you have a notion of "rank" that is either an ordinal or $\infty$, it's convenient to say it satisfies $\infty>\infty$; for instance, this is done in *Steel forcing*).

Comment: Hummm. What about the formula $\phi(x) = \forall y,z (TREES(x)=y \wedge \gamma(x)=z \to y>z)$? This one looks like it'd be true in all models, for all $x$, since in those models that think one or both of the functions are nontotal, the antecedent is false. Correct? So what about $\forall x \phi(x)$, is this sentence provable? If not, how so? If yes, then what about it makes it different to $\sigma$?

Comment: Note that any sentence involving "$TREES$" or "$\gamma$" *isn't* a fully meaningful sentence in arithmetic - since those aren't symbols in the language of arithmetic! They're definable functions, of course, but then *statements in terms of them* are open to interpretation: e.g. when you write "$TREES(x)=y$", is that shorthand for "If $TREES(x)$ is defined, then it equals $y$" or "$TREES(x)$ is defined and equals $y$"? This is what I'm asking you to clear up. (cont'd)

Comment: It sounds like you want to ask about the sentence, "For all but finitely many $x$, if $TREES(x)$ and $\gamma(x)$ are both defined, then $TREES(x)>\gamma(x)$"; is this right? *This* is a clear sentence - call it "$\sigma_1$" - and your question makes sense for it. However, you could just as easily ask about $\sigma_2$ - "For all but finitely many $x$, if $TREES(x)$ is defined then $\gamma(x)$ is also defined and $\gamma(x)<TREES(x)$". $\sigma_2$ is a stronger condition - e.g., it rules out having $TREES(x)=17$ and $\gamma(x)$ be undefined. (To my mind, $\gamma$ is "bigger" in such a case.)

Comment: Oh, I see the distinction. I shouldn't have used functions - I am not sure how logic deals with functions at undefined values [how does it deal?]. Let $M(x,y)$ be the predicate asserting "machine $M$ - that computes $TREES$ - when ran on $x$ halts exactly at step $y$", and similarly for $N(x,y)$ [so I guess it is the second, stronger assertion - "is defined and is so and so"]. Then $\phi(x)$ becomes "$\forall y,z (M(x,y) \wedge N(x,z) \to y > z)$". So this sentence will be true for all $x$ in all models [I presume]. Then what about $\forall x \phi(x)$?

Comment: The answer to how logic deals with functions with undefined values is - however you want it to! If I have a definable partial function $f$, I can talk about its *totalization* - let $\hat{f}(x)=f(x)$ if the latter is defined, and $0$ otherwise (see e.g. the $\mu$ operator in recursion theory). Or, and more commonly, we can treat it as a *relation* - $R(x, y)$ holds iff $f(x)$ is defined and equals $y$. (cont'd)

Comment: Indeed, we can treat total functions this way too - and there are often cases where it is useful to pass from a given theory to an "equivalent" (=biinterpretable) one in a language consisting of only relation symbols (e.g. Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games). The important thing is that this isn't done for you - *you* have to specify how you're encoding the various informal statements you care about. As to the sentence you're interested in - I strongly suspect it is indeed provable in PA, but I don't know that for a fact. (I would, however, edit your question to make it more precise.)